# Is there a way to calculate the magnitude of the difference in means in R?

Tags: r, mean, kruskal-wallis-test

I have a dataset with a non-Gaussian distribution - signalment and body measurements of three species of bird. I have used the Kruskal-Wallis with post-hoc Dunn Test and Bonferroni correction tests to determine that the mean weight of the three species are significantly different. I now want to test the hypothesis that the females of two of the species are at least 25% heavier than males. What is the best way to do this in R? I.e. I know that females are significantly heavier, but I want to quantify it.

Dataset here:
https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/Rdatasets/csv/Stat2Data/Hawks.csv

```
    # Does Weight look Gaussian?

hawkish <- read.csv("hawkish.csv")

hist(hawkish$Weight)

library(car)

qqPlot(hawkish$Weight)

hist(log(hawkish$Weight))
qqPlot(log(hawkish$Weight))

shapiro.test(log(hawkish$Weight))
```

I have looked at the distributions for individual species and you can see they look Gaussian, but shapiro.test() <0.001

```
hist(hawkish$Weight[hawkish$Species == "RT"])
qqPlot(hawkish$Weight[hawkish$Species == "RT"])
shapiro.test(hawkish$Weight[hawkish$Species == "RT"])

hist(hawkish$Weight[hawkish$Species == "SS"])
qqPlot(hawkish$Weight[hawkish$Species == "SS"])
shapiro.test(hawkish$Weight[hawkish$Species == "SS"])

hist(hawkish$Weight[hawkish$Species == "CH"])
qqPlot(hawkish$Weight[hawkish$Species == "CH"])
shapiro.test(hawkish$Weight[hawkish$Species == "CH"])
```

Thanks :)

Comment: Kruskal-Wallis is not a general test for differences of means. Your hypothesis is perhaps better rephrased as about a difference in the mean of log weight, I can't advise about use of R. .

Comment: I have tried to log-transform the data, but it doesn't help. The data still looks non-Gaussian and has a shapiro.test p-value of <0.001. Before transformation the data looks Gaussian on a histogram and qq-plot but still has a shapiro.test p-value of <0.001. It is for a university assignment and my lecturer has said that despite visual appraisal and sample size, you should still assume non-Gaussianity if it doesn't "pass" the Shapiro Wilk test.

Comment: If you're instructed to test that hypothesis, it's a hypothesis about a difference in logarithms. What your instructor expects you to do is naturally something you can discuss only with them. A t test for difference in means can work fairly well so long as two groups have about the same skewness. I'd be surprised if log weight wasn't less skewed than weight, but watch out for outliers

Comment: Sorry; if you have males and females and then three species you need analysis of variance to look at a difference in means, but as said I suspect that log weight will behave better and is the scale on which being 25% heavier can be quantified as a difference. Using separate t tests for each species is perhaps not ideal but may be easier to think about in some ways.

Comment: Could you augment your post with some plots, or maybe even share (a link to) your data?

Comment: Thank you, Nick, this is helping me understand a topic that is totally alien. I will augment my post with some code. Thanks again.